# What does "Stateless function components cannot be given refs" mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this:

```
const ProjectsSummaryLayout = ({projects}) => {
   return (
      <div className="projects-summary col-md-10">
          <h3>Projects</h3>
          <ul>
              { projects.map(p => <li key={p.id}>{p.contract.client}</li>) }
          </ul>
      </div>
   )
}

const ProjectsSummary = connect(
   state => ({projects: state.projects})
)(ProjectsSummaryLayout)
```

and I get:

> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs (See ref
>   "wrappedInstance" in ProjectsSummaryLayout created by
>   Connect(ProjectsSummaryLayout)). Attempts to access this ref will
>   fail.

What is it trying to tell me?   Am I actually doing something wrong?

I see discussion about this [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/141) but unfortunately I simply don't understand the conclusion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In React, [`refs` may not be attached to a stateless component](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936).

React Redux **3** attaches a `ref` to the component you give it **regardless** of whether or not it's stateless. The warning you see comes from React because internally, React Redux 3 attaches a `ref` to the  stateless component you supplied (`ProjectsSummaryLayout`).

You're not doing anything wrong and according to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/141#issuecomment-148358733), you can safely ignore the warning.

In React Redux **4**, no `ref` is attached to the wrapped component by default, which means if you upgrade to React Redux 4, the warning should go away.

Comment: Noticed the same issue with react-dnd.

Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

Check the render method of `DragSource(Component)`.

Answer (score 3):

React has 2 commonly used component styles.

- Functional Component
- Class Component

So, When I was making use of Functional one then I was encountering this error.
[image: error encountered when I was using functional component]

Code snippet corresponding to Functional Component

[image: code for square component]

But as soon as I changed it to Class Component then it worked.

[image: it worked]

Code snippet corresponding to Class Component.

[image]

Try changing Functional Component to Class Component.
I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: This is masking the problem, in this case you should just use `React.forwardRef`