# react-scrollable-anchor is not working properly

Tags: reactjs

npm react-scrollable-anchor for some reason not working properly. I can only jump to the id attribute only in `<section>` tag, not sure why.

I have tried libraries including, react-scrollable-anchor, react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll, and react-scrollchor. None of them working properly. I can at most see that there is a hash tag in my url, but page doesn't scroll at all. I have to use `<section>` tag in order to jump to the section. Other than that, my page doesn't move at all. I'm assuming that I don't need to react-router in order to achieve scrolling.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Welcome from './sections/welcome/welcome';
import Artists from './sections/artists/homepageArtists';

import ScrollableAnchor from 'react-scrollable-anchor';
import { configureAnchors } from 'react-scrollable-anchor'
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import './Home.css';

const dots = [
{ className: 'navDots', name: 'Welcome', section: "#welcome", num: '1', to:"#welcome"},
{ className: 'navDots', name: 'Artists', section: "#artists", num: '2', to:"#artists"},
]

class PageSection extends Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.content;
    }
}

PageSection.propTypes = {
    content: PropTypes.node.isRequired
}

class Home extends Component {
    render() {

    return (
        <div>

            <div className="homepage">
                <div className="homepage-title">
                    <div className="dots-group">
                        {dots.map((dot) => (
                            <span className={dot.className} key={dot.name}>
                                <a href={dot.section}> go </a>
                            </span>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


            <ScrollableAnchor id={"welcome"}>
                <PageSection content={<Welcome />} />
            </ScrollableAnchor>
            <ScrollableAnchor id={"artists"}>
                <PageSection content={<Artists />} />
            </ScrollableAnchor>

            <section id='welcome'>
                <PageSection content={<Welcome />} />
             </section>
             <section id='artists'>
                <PageSection content={<Artists />} />
             </section> 
        </div>
     }
   }
}
```

I expect that it should scroll to the id section when I click the anchor tag. My react version is 16.5.2 if this matters?

Comment: The scrollable behavior works as expected (https://react-sfzst9.stackblitz.io). Confirm that you don't have some extensions messing with clicks. You can try in browsing the application in incognito

Comment: It's weird when I try your react-sfzst9.stackblitz.io, and it's working. What extensions are you referring to? What's incognito?

Comment: I just test in incognito, but it's still the same. Only jump to the id sections. What extensions might cause this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure about specific browser extensions that might cause that. Since you said it's the same browsing your application in Incognito, I think the problem doesn't lie with browser extensions.

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollableAnchor` in `react-scrollable-anchor` library forwards refs for its children when it renders.

```
render() {
  const {children, id} = this.props

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    ref: children.ref || id,
  })
}
```

**[View Source](https://github.com/gabergg/react-scrollable-anchor/blob/56994b13c08b6c04500cdcfb3806e1815b4fc94e/src/ScrollableAnchor.js#L29)**

When scrollable anchors are implemented with stateless functional components like so

```
const Welcome = props => {
  return (<div {...props}>Welcome!</div>)
}

const Artists = props => {
  return (<div {...props}>These are artists!</div>)
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ScrollableAnchor id={"welcome"}>
      <Welcome style={{ height: 600 }}/>
    </ScrollableAnchor>
    <ScrollableAnchor id={"artists"}>
      <Artists style={{ height: 800 }} />
    </ScrollableAnchor>
  </div>
)
```

There is a console warning that must be given attention to:

> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.
>
> Check the render method of `ScrollableAnchor`.
>
> in Welcome (created by ScrollableAnchor)
>
> in ScrollableAnchor (created by App)
>
> in div (created by App)
>
> in App

Refs are not allowed to be set on stateless components since they don't have instances. Refer to this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953061/5189811) for more conversation about that.

To address this warning, you can either implement the stateless components as stateful ones or create a stateful container as below:

```
class PageSection extends Component {
   render() {
     return this.props.content
   }
}
PageSection.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.node.isRequired
}
```

This above `PageSection` stateful container can be used in the App component as follow.

```
<ScrollableAnchor id={"welcome"}>
  <PageSection content={<Welcome style={{ height: 600 }}/>} />
</ScrollableAnchor>
<ScrollableAnchor id={"artists"}>
  <PageSection content={<Artists style={{ height: 800 }}/>} />
</ScrollableAnchor>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sfzst9?file=index.js) with the complete code.

Since `react-scrollable-anchor` was developed for React 15, it uses deprecated API of `ReactDOM` such as `findDOMNode` that may removed in later versions of React 16 so I suggest to look to informing the maintainers about that and possibly contributing an update.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I appreciate your time, but it is still not working, unfortunately... My Welcome and Artist are class components. And  I have tried to follow your suggestion, but my url still changes but the page is still not moving. I tried to research if this is React version problem, but I don't find anything. Please see my updated code.

Comment: If I may ask, what browser are you running the application in?

Comment: I'm using Chrome to develop, and I'm planing to make it run in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox in production later on. Do you think these browsers matter?

Comment: Definitely! It's a good practice to have your application accessible in major browsers. I'm running the StackBlitz sample in Chrome and Safari and unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I also feel the same way :) So it's fine on your end when you run in Chrome or Safari?

Comment: Regardless of the error warning, it still works.  So there is something else wrong with the code.